# Which is correct 'suits your needs the best' or 'best suits your needs'?

Tags: word-order

Which one is correct:

> 'Something suits your needs **the best**' or
>
> 'Something **best** suits your needs'?

Comment: Either one is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Either is fine, but (American here) I think "Something that best suits your needs" would be the most common way of saying it.